# Warning: gzdecode(): data error in wp-config.php: runtime-created function

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings, eval

I'm running WP 3.5.2 and am encountering the following error:

> **Warning**:  gzdecode(): data error in [path]\wwwroot\wp-config.php(1) : runtime-created function(1) :
>   eval()'d code on line **29**

I've looked at all the calls to `eval()` in my site & can't find anything unusual. I've looked at all instances of calls to `gzdecode` & there's nothing obviously wrong. If I look at line 29 of `wp-config.php`, there's `define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.org');`

I've searched and the only references I can find that are for the same data error mimic my error message exactly (down to the line 29 part) -- and these are all apparently live sites, not something that yields troubleshooting help.

I've tried switching back to twenty-twelve & twenty-eleven. I've disabled all plugins. Nothing seems to make any difference.

Any suggestions on where to start my search would be most definitely appreciated!

Comment: Your site has been hacked.

Comment: Suggestions on how to go about fixing it?

Comment: delete and replace from your backups

Answer (score 0):

gzdecode relates to gzip functionality inside Apache and/or Wordpress. follow the gzdecode error, go upstream, you may have to perform a re-install of libraries.

I would look at your php_info() output and see what libraries are active in php and modules on in apache.

I would look in those places with your server configuration. php and apache may need to be restarted once you've reinstalled the compression libs.

Either way, I would roll-up a new instance of your site from backups from 30 days prior, then apply all the updates for WordPress, Apache, Linux, etc (not sure where this site sits for you and how much access/control you have.) And then start pushing data refreshes in to bring you forward to the last week of your data.

Pull down all relevant log files from that server.

Install a WordPress Security plugin. There's lots of good ones out there. Be Proactive and keep up with your updates and backups.

Best of luck.